# didSelectRowAt called only on multitouch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

What can make `UITableViewCell` detect only multitouch? If I tap with one finger it doesn't call `didSelectRowAtIndex`.

Here is my Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookingSettingsCell", for: indexPath) as! SettingsTableViewCell
    if indexPath.row < 3 {
        cell.settingSwitch.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    cell.settingTitle.text = dataForSetting[indexPath.row].first
    if dataForSetting[indexPath.row].last != "Pencil" {
        cell.settingValue.isHidden = true
        cell.settingChangable.isHidden = true
        cell.settingSwitch.isHidden = false
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        if indexPath.row < 3 {
            let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DatePicker") as! DatePickerViewController
            destinationVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            destinationVC.delegate = self
            self.present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

**UITableViewCell class:**

```
class SettingsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet var settingTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var settingChangable: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var settingValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var settingSwitch: UISwitch!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        settingSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.65, y: 0.60)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you put your code inside DispatchQueue.main.async?
Remove it and try.

Comment: I've added it cause if I do not it has long delay before presenting VC (I've found this solution long time ago) and 100% sure it is not the real problem.

Comment: The same code is working fine in my case

Comment: you meant something like double tap on cell .. ?

Comment: nope touch with 2 or more fingers

Comment: Yes it may possible but you must implement gesture recognizer which may cause disable `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method ..

Comment: exactly, that was the problem but why is worked with multitouch?

Comment: not sure but multi touch may cause undefined behavior anyway i think you got your solution ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the behavior of `uitableviews's` `didSelectRowAt` method after implementing the delegate methods of gesture recognizer. This prevents the undefined behavior of taps between `uiview` and `tableViewCell` and keeps the record of touches.

**UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method:**

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    println("in shouldReceiveTouch")
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    if (touch.view == tableView){
        println("touching tableView list")
        return false
    }
    else{
        println("touching elsewhere")
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that this happened because I added `UITapGestureRecognizer`to my superview so I can hide keyboard on touch. But actually still don't understand why in this case it worked with multitouch? I would suggest that my mistake should block all tap events.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem isn't in didSelectRowAt but in a UITableViewCell...
are you using the constraint logic when you design the xib?
Is possible that some object (label or imageView) create problem with touch...
review your constraint or design your tableViewCell direct in uitableView from storyboard.

Comment: I've designed it in storyboard. The problem is that as far as I know it should either detect touch (all good) or do not detect (some view overlaying etc.) , but it detect multitouch only, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by adding the **UIGesture recogniser delegate** in your class. Add the  **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** in your class. Follow these steps:-

/*

```
class SignupInstructorViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

**Note:-** Now for identify whether you are tapping on tableView or some where else you have to implement this gesture delegate like this.

//MARK:- Gesture delegates

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    // if user touch the tableview then below condition will be true
    if touch.view != nil && (touch.view!.isDescendantOfView(tableViewName)) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

HopeFully, it will works for you.

Thanks in Advance.

*/

Answer (score 0):

You can check if this happens due to any gesture by removing all the gestures of the view as below and try.

```
view.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
```

Better to find the exact gesture which cause the issue and handle it properly.