# UITableView swipe gesture conflicts with UITableViewCell swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swtableviewcell

Following is the code I have written to put 2 finger swipe on `UITableView` :

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [UISwipeGestureRecognizer new];
[leftSwipe addTarget:self action:@selector(nextDay)];
leftSwipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
leftSwipe.delegate = self;
[leftSwipe setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
[tableViewTasks addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipe];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [UISwipeGestureRecognizer new];
[rightSwipe addTarget:self action:@selector(previousDay)];
rightSwipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
rightSwipe.delegate = self;
[rightSwipe setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
[tableViewTasks addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipe];
```

I am using [**SWTableViewCell**](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) which has left and right (single tap) gestureRecognisers.
When `UITableView` is swiped left/right using 2 fingers, `SWTableViewCell` left and right gestures are also fired after that.
How to stop the conflict ?

Comment: if it can be solved by using gesture delegate, just have a look [this past ans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39806768/4003548) and figure out.

Comment: - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya : Done that already. Still facing the issue.

Comment: @Nitish did you upload any gif or video that show your problem .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya : Let me try.

Comment: @Nitish why dont you disable editing of rows in tableview. it will stop the swipe gesture of tableview to detect anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    if (SWTableViewCellTouch) {
        SWTableViewCellTouch = NO
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

when you touch the SWTableViewCell set a BOOL SWTableViewCellTouch to YES.

Comment: This does help but still there appears to be a minor conflict. It seems like I have to swipe on the table hard so as to avoid conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution is enable/disable the BOOl (SWTableViewCellTouch) in the touchesBegan: method as below.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   if ([[event touchesForView:self] count] > 1) {
   // Its two finger touch so set the BOOL false like
   SWTableViewCellTouch = NO;
   }
   else if ([[event touchesForView:self] count] == 1){
    // Its sigle finger touch so set the BOOL true like
    SWTableViewCellTouch = YES;
   }
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event] ;}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in your `UIViewController`

**2.** Set `leftSwipe.delegate = self;` and `leftSwipe.delegate = self;`

**3.** Now check if the  in its Delegate Method if UISwipeGesture have how many `numberOfTouchesRequired`

```
 -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
    {
    if ( [gestureRecognizer isMemberOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]] ) {

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer  *swipeGesture=(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer ;

    if(swipeGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired!=2)
     {    
    //if Double not Double Swipe Touch Don't Linsten Gesture in your Viewcontroller
     return NO;
      }
     }

        return YES; 
    }
```

i hope this will solve your problem